# How show a value when clicking on a table row

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-framework, typescript

I am a beginner with sharepoint and typescript, i have dynamic table, and i want to get value of row when i click on

```
  private _renderList(items: ISPList[]): void {


let html: string = '<table class="TFtable" border=1 width=40% style="border-collapse: collapse;">';
html += `<th>Catégories</th>`;
items.forEach((item: ISPList) => {
html += `
<tr>

<td >${item.Categorie.Title}</td>

</tr>
`;
});

html += `</table>`;
/* html+= `<ul class="${styles.list}">
<li class="${styles.listItem}">
<span class="ms-font-l">${item.Question}</span>
</li>
</ul>`;*/


const listContainer: Element = this.domElement.querySelector('#spListContainer');
listContainer.innerHTML = html;

}
```

Comment: Is there any way you can provide a bit more detail?  What are you trying to display? Is it when you click on a row in the list table? Sorry, but I am unclear as to what you are trying to accomplish.  Thanks!

Comment: i have a dynamic table; i want get the value of the row whene i click on it

Answer (score 0):

Modify the code as below.

```
private _renderList(items: ISPList[]): void {

    let tbl = document.createElement("table");
    tbl.setAttribute("class", "TFtable");
    tbl.setAttribute("border", "1");
    tbl.setAttribute("width", "100%");
    tbl.setAttribute("style", "border-collapse: collapse;");
    let tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");
    let headRow  = document.createElement("tr");
    let cell = document.createElement("th");
    let cellText = document.createTextNode("Catégories");
    cell.appendChild(cellText);
    headRow.appendChild(cell);
    tblBody.appendChild(headRow);
    items.forEach((item: ISPList) => {
      let currentRow  = document.createElement("tr");    
      let cell = document.createElement("td");      
      let cellText = document.createTextNode(`${item.Categorie.Title}`);
      cell.appendChild(cellText);
      currentRow.appendChild(cell);
      let createClickHandler = function(row: HTMLTableRowElement) {
        return function() {
          let tdValue = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0].innerHTML;  
          alert("Value:" + tdValue);
        };
      };
      currentRow.onclick=createClickHandler(currentRow);
      tblBody.appendChild(currentRow);
    });
    tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
    document.getElementById("spListContainer").appendChild(tbl);
}
```

Comment: Thank you; can you explain me more please; we use UI Fabric ?